# How do you create a PHP variable whom all scripts can access?

Tags: php, session

I want to create a sort of super-global variable whom all scripts can access. I cannot use $_SESSION variables because multiple clients will be accessing that variable. Is there a way?

Edit:
Saving it in DB will work, but I don't wana do that because it is just a single variable... And I do not want to add latency of accessing DB for it.

Comment: Take a look at $GLOBALS

Comment: In what way is it a variable? It sounds to me like a database setting or a configuration file may be more suitable than some kind of variable.

Comment: It says: "An associative array containing references to all variables which are currently defined in the global scope of the SCRIPT".. from which I infer that they will not be accessible from different scripts.

Comment: @lonesomeday Yes, DB will work, but I cannot stand the latency to access db or read a file.. It is just a single variable, there should be a way

Comment: @CashifIlyas In that case you'll probably need to write a PHP file with the variable you want to set and `require` it. This isn't common behaviour (or a common requirement) so there is no "simple" way.

Comment: @lonesomeday No, I can't do that.. Scripts need to change it at run time

Comment: Reading a file is not a problem as usually applications read a lot of files every time page is opened. Just create single file with all settings and your variable.

Comment: @CashifIlyas PHP doesn't work like that. Each request runs in a different thread (well, this depends on the system setup, but it's generally a good assumption) so the requests do not have access to each others' variables. You're asking for something that PHP doesn't really do. (NB that scripts *could* change an included file, but it would admittedly be a lot of hassle.)

Comment: How about memcache? Or even better: set you variable in a file.php, write function to get the variable, where if it not exists in memcache ->take from functuion->save to memcache

Comment: Yes, some sort of shared memory is probably what you want. There's shmop, APC, memcache, Redis etc. Which one to pick depends on what exactly you're using this for.